# ylabel axis value 1e6 change

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a bar chart of active covid cases for my lab classes from pandas dataframe. Although I am not satisfied with the y axis and it's reference which is 1E6 How can i change that?

My DF

[image]

And I plot graph this way

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax = newdf[['confirmed','deaths']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Covid most active cases countries",figsize=(15,10),legend=True, fontsize=12,color=['blue','green'])
ax.set_xlabel("Countires",fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Cases",fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the y-axis

- first graph is default formatter that gives same result as you note
- second graph formats as millions

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=[14,6], sharex=True)

df = pd.json_normalize(requests.get("https://corona-api.com/countries").json()["data"])
dfp = (df.loc[:,["name","latest_data.deaths","latest_data.confirmed"]]
 .set_index("name")
 .sort_values("latest_data.deaths",ascending=False)
 .head(20)
)
dfp.plot(ax=ax[0], kind="bar")
dfp.plot(ax=ax[1], kind="bar")

ax[1].get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x)//10**6, ',')))
```

[image]